# Parent div with floating children unresponsive

Tags: html, css

My first issue is that the boxes are not aligning properly like this:

[image]
And the 2nd issue is that I'm trying to make a responsive div where the `rightHand` parent `div` shrinks responsively while having the floating children also collapse responsively into a single row where each cube would take from it's parent a quarter of the width of it's parent.

Here's [my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/pd05tf2s/)

```css
.rightHand {
  height: 100%;
  width: 680px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.rightHandOverlay {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.rightHand p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.redBox {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.greenBox {
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
.blueBox {
  float: right;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellowBox {
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='rightHand'>
  <div class="box redBox"></div>
  <div class="box greenBox"></div>
  <p>hi this is a test</p>
  <div class="box blueBox"></div>
  <div class="box yellowBox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , Can you post The code over the question?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao now that you have my code in the question (even though there's a fiddle) - you can answer now? :) How many points do ppl get on putting comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean something like that?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ghost080/unfr4s08/2/)

```
.rightHand {
      height: 100%;
      width: 680px;
      float: right;
      background-color: #000000;
    }

    .rightHand p {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .box {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }

    .redBox {
      background-color: red;
      float: left;
    }

    .greenBox {
      float: right;
      background-color: green;
    }

    .blueBox {

      clear:left;
      bottom: 0;
      float: right;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .yellowBox {
      float: left;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

Comment: you solved my first issue, thanks. But it's not responsive as to what I wrote mate.

Comment: i updated it and added an animation to make it clear that it will break like you want to if the width of the boxes exceeds 100%.

Comment: Hey, that animation kind of confused me at start but now I understand what you've shown me, awesome answer.